# Probability of matching faces on 2 separate pools of d10s

Tags: probability

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this.

I am trying to figure out the probability for one separate d10 to have a matching face with a pool of d10 comprised by up to 5 other d10s.

So just to make myself clear, if I roll up to 5 d10s and a separate d10 of a different color, what are the chances that said die matches with any of the other d10s?

I would like to know this probability for all 5 combinations (1d10,2d10,3d10,4d10 and 5d10 + the separate d10).

Also, after calculating the probability, if the "colored" die gets rolled twice, does the probability of at least one face matching simply double?

Cheers

Comment: OK. Do you expect that we answer all 6 question? I prefer the rule: "1 post, 1 question". What were your thoughts about the first question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one colored die, and you're comparing it to a pool of $N$ other dice, then the probability that any match your colored die is 1 minus the probability that they all mismatch.

The d10 has 10 sides, so the probability of a single mismatch is $(10-1)/10=0.9$.

And so the probability of $N$ mismatches is $0.9^N$.

The general formula for one d10 matching at least one die in a pool of $N$ other d10s is

$$P(N) = 1 - (0.9)^N$$

For the examples you gave,
$$P(1)=0.1$$
$$P(2)=0.19$$
$$P(3)=0.271$$
$$P(4)=0.3439$$
$$P(5)=0.40951$$

And the general formula for comparing an $X$-sided die versus a $N$-sized pool of $X$-sided dice would be

$$P(X,N) = 1 - ((X-1)/X)^N$$

Doubling the dice in the colored pool does not simply double the probability. I don't know the general formula, so I wrote up a matlab program to simulate all possible rolls, and got these values:

$$P_2(1)=0.19$$
$$P_2(2)=0.343$$
$$P_2(3)=0.4663$$
$$P_2(4)=0.5657$$
$$P_2(5)=0.646$$

Comment: Minor observation: At the end of your first paragraph, you write "...is 1 - the probability that they all mismatch."  It took me a moment to realize that you didn't mean "...is 1—that is, the probability that they all mismatch," but rather "...is 1 minus the probability that they all mismatch."  Maybe write out the minus sign?

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks for the advice, I made the edit

Comment: @Carcosa Thank you for your reply!