# Probability of M&Ms matching colors

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

In my office, we have a small toy M&M vending machine that dispenses about a handful of M&Ms at a time. My coworker began a game of asking me if there at least 2 M&Ms of the same color out of 4 M&Ms dispensed. So he carefully gets 4 M&Ms from the toy vending machine. The machine holds probably about 200 M&Ms (not sure if that's important) that we regularly refill. The source of M&Ms has 6 colors. Our initial guess is that there's a 50% chance of a match. (3 chances that the color matches the first drawn M&M, so 3 out of 6 for 50%).

If we assume that the colors are in equal proportions (which they are not), are we correct in assuming the 50% probability?

$$\frac{3}{6}=0.5$$

On the other hand, if we break down each probability:

- First Draw: Not considered.
- Second Draw: 1 out of 6 probability of matching the first draw.
- Third Draw: 2 out of 6 probability of matching the first or second
  draw.
- Fourth Draw: 3 out of 6 probability of matching the first, second, or
  third draw.
  $$\frac{1}{6}*\frac{2}{6}*\frac{3}{6}=0.0278$$

But that seems wrong.

We are not mathematicians or statistician in this office btw. We are writers and researchers - so please go easy on me! We tried to ask one of our engineers, but he got obsessed with the design of the toy vending machine.

My question seems similar to this one, but not sure if that got answered: [Probability of matching faces on 2 separate pools of d10s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777242/probability-of-matching-faces-on-2-separate-pools-of-d10s).

Comment: It is easier to approach the opposite way... finding the probability that none match and subtracting away from $1$.  You have $1-\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{6}=\frac{13}{18}\approx 0.72$.  This problem, for the record, is essentially the birthday problem (*but with only 6 possibilities rather than the full 365*).

Comment: I lol'd at the engineer part

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks! That makes sense!

Comment: In case you get excited and start wondering about how likely it is for at least three M&Ms to match and other such sundry office problems, here is the general soln: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirthdayProblem.html

Comment: While you have the answer already, I always think its a good idea to point out where you went wrong. In the first guess, your logic was that since you draw three after the first one, the probability would be $3/6$. But if this was how it worked, then if you drew $7$ M&M's, you'd have a $6/6$ chance, which clearly is wrong.